# Calculate $\int_0^\pi\frac{x\sin x}{1+\cos^2x}dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals, change-of-variable

Please could you help me calculate the next integral:

$$\int_0^\pi\dfrac{x\sin x}{1+\cos^2x}dx$$

Thank you.

Comment: no effort + duplicate -> close vote

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $$\int_0^{\pi} xf(\sin x) \, \mathrm{d}x = \frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^{\pi} f(\sin x) \, \mathrm{d}x$$ via $x \mapsto \pi-x$.

So here you have (remember that $\cos^2 x = 1-\sin^2 x)$ $$\int_0^{\pi} \frac{x\sin x}{1+\cos^2 x} \, \mathrm{d}x = \frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^{\pi} \frac{\sin x}{1+\cos^2 x} \, \mathrm{d}x.$$

Now use $x \mapsto \cos x$ to get $$\int_0^{\pi} \frac{x\sin x}{1+\cos^2 x}\, \mathrm{d}x = \frac{\pi}{2}\int_{-1}^1 \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{1+x^2} = \frac{\pi}{2}\cdot \frac{\pi}{2} = \frac{\pi^2}{4}.$$

Comment: I actually got $\frac{\pi^2}{4}$

Comment: $\pi^2/4$ is correct.

Comment: Corrected. Stupid blunder with my limits. (Thanks!)